# RichEditBox: picture and content after the picture disappear (Windows 10 1703 Creators Update)

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, richeditbox

In Windows 10 1703 Creators Update a new bug appeared.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Load an RTF document with a picture into RichEditBox
2. Save it.
3. Save it again.
4. Reload it or open it with another app - you will see that the picture is gone and all the content after it is gone too.

I submitted [this bug here](https://aka.ms/Tr5rmc) in FeedbackHub app.

The question is *how to avoid this bug or make a workaround?*

Answer (score 1):

[This project on GitHub is to demonstrate the bug and to fix it.](https://github.com/artemious7/TestOfRicheditboxPictureBug)

After you save the document for the 2-nd time, the picture is gone, but the closing brace '}' for the picture block is still there, so all the content that comes after the brace '}' cannot be read.

So we simply remove the odd brace and restore the picture that was gone using the same document (but unchanged one).